# Symfony2 & EmberJS: how to make both prod and dev (/app_dev.php/...) urls working?

Tags: symfony, ember.js

Say my application currently responds to the `/products` route just fine. How do I setup Ember.JS so that /app_dev.php/products would be the same route?

Comment: Could you not use a `DEBUG` "constant" in your Ember application that added the `app_dev.php` to your routes if set to true? If you are using UglifyJS you could compile your final script without all of your dev "ifs" by using `--define DEBUG=false`.

Comment: @Qoop Well, I think I can. But isn't there a way to make mirrored routing in EmberJS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you need to generate Symf route via js instead of static "/products" route?

If so you should use FOSJsRoutingBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Just set option "expose" to your routing as:

## app/config/routing.yml

```
my_products:
    pattern: /products
    defaults: { _controller: ProductBundle:Products:index }
    options:
        expose: true
```

then you can generate the route depends on env from javascript as:

```
Routing.generate('my_products')
```